# Android - What is the maximum number of downloads can be done in google drive?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have uploaded the file in the google drive and I am downloading that file in the android app. I know that google maps has some restriction like if the number of hits reaches 2500 per day, it will display the error message, for more that 2500 we need to pay to google.

Is there any restriction for google drive also. If so what is the maximum limit?

Answer (score 1):

As the Docs & Drive Community Manager approves, the answer is given [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/qcbDorj-vYE).